# AWS Kinesis, Is S3 mandatory to be used for kinesis?

Tags: amazon-kinesis, apache-camel-aws-kinesis

Could you please provide some clarity on s3 usage in Kinesis?

Thanks,
Subham

Comment: _Why_ do you ask? What are you wanting to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to use Amazon S3 with Amazon Kinesis.

You can have a producer that sends data to a Kinesis stream, and you can have a consumer that reads messages from a Kinesis stream.

Amazon S3 is not required in this process.